# How to pass params to POST method in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, post, parameters, angular2-services

I want to Pass parameters to POST method in angular 2 but it is not working whwn I used **params:new httpParams().set()** but it is not worked .I also tried **params:new httpParams().set() and headers** then also it is not worked & finally I got the solution with **Formdata**

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569409/angular-2-http-post-params-and-body?rq=1) have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I checked that link but it is laso not worked

Comment: Below is the right answer of my question

Answer (score 5):

You can use formData to send http params or any kind of attachment.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

// http request with post method
this.httpService.post('Url', formData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Their is way to pass data to post method in angular 2 by using the **Formdata**,while passing the data their is no need of headers because we are using the formdata here.
     To understand this concept lets take one example as-

```
    saveNewData(name, countryId) {
    this.saveNewDataUrl = 'localhost:7575/app/data';

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('name', name);
    fd.append('countryId', countryId);

    return this.http.post(this.saveNewDataUrl, fd);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
var validFileExtensions: string[] = ['jpg', 'jpeg','png']; 

      this.uploadedFiles.append('id', this.userInfo.id.toString());
      this.uploadedFiles.append('validImageExtensions', validFileExtensions.toString());

      this.accountService.uploadImage(this.uploadedFiles).subscribe((result: any) => {

        this.alertService.success("Profile settings updated successfully");
      },
```